# Why VS code detects only some of my python libraries?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

The problem started when my python extension displayed "reload required". I pressed on it and after it reloaded VS code, I noticed it stopped suggesting autocompletes anything related to pygame. I don't really know how to explain it but in the given picture it highlights pyautogui library green but not pygame. It doesn't change the color of any methods of pygame as well. The biggest thing bothering me is not the color, but it doesn't suggest anything for autocomplete. Note: The program doesn't give any error about libraries while running. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zE7F.png)

I tried reinstalling VSCode, python extension and the library itself but nothing worked and found nothing on the internet that helps.

Comment: What python extension are you using?

Comment: I think it is called pylance

Comment: Actually I would have advise you to use pylance in case you were not using it already. I believe many people are more skilled than me to help you in that case.